# Как передать два параметра в представление?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть две таблицы - `Rubric` и `Question`. Связь один ко многим. Стоит задача отредактировать `Question` с привязкой к `Rubric`. Я делаю выборку из обоих таблиц. Не совсем понятно, как использовать данные из рубрик, чтобы привязать их к вопросу.

```
  def edit
    @rubrics = Rubric.where(rubric_type: :question);
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end


<%= render 'validation_errors', object: @question %>
<%= form_for [:admin, @question], html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :question %>
        <%= f.trix_editor :question %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :answer %>
        <%= f.trix_editor :answer%>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :created_at %>
        <%= f.label :created_at %>
    </p>
    <%= f.select :rubric %>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать рубрики во вьюху можно и как у вас - это приемлемый вариант. А показать рубрики в селекте в форме можно так:

```
= f.collection_select :rubric_id, @rubrics, :id, :title,
                      { prompt: 'Выберите рубрику' },
                      { class: 'select' }
```

где:

- `rubric_id` - параметр `@question`, с которым связываем данный селект;
- `@rubrics` - коллекция, по которой построятся пункты селекта;
- `:id` - это поле элементов коллекции ляжет в основу `value` пунктов селекта;
- `:title` - из этого поля построятся названия ваших пунктов.